# Como faço para que as imagens internas do ASIDE ajustem a sua altura e largura automaticamente?

Tags: css, html5

Como faço para que as imagens internas do `ASIDE` ajustem a sua altura e largura automaticamente de acordo com o redimensionamento do navegador?

**CSS**

```
aside{
  background-color: #222;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
aside figure{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

aside figure img{ /* redimensionar imagem */
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<aside>


        <figure>
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./imagens/praias.png" width="300" height="400">
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure>
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./imagens/praias.png" width="300" height="400">
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure>
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./imagens/praias.png" width="300" height="400">
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure>
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./imagens/praias.png" width="300" height="400">
            </a>
        </figure>

    </aside>
```

Comment: Por quê as imagens possuem `width` e `height` definidos se a dimensão é controlada pelo CSS? Essas propriedades possuem prioridade maior que o CSS e nunca serão sobrescritas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como posso fazer os ajustes no html e no css? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Começa removendo esses atributos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss poderia reescrever este código para mim?

Comment: Tente você fazer primeiro, assim aprenderá mais.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss removi os atributos

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61259/discussion-between-gladison-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 0):

**O CSS**

Pensando no responsivo, vamos deixar nossos itens em % para 2 colunas seguindo dessa forma:

Para cada item apliquei 50% em width

Selecionamos o primeiro item para zerar o margin usando o seletor “:first-of-type”.

```css
.highlights {
     position: relative;
}

.highlights-item {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   width: 50%;
}

.highlights-item:first-of-type {
   margin-left: 0;
}

.highlights-item img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
    <figure class="highlights-item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://palloi.github.io/responsive-header-only-css/assets/images/chaves.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="highlights-item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://palloi.github.io/responsive-header-only-css/assets/images/chaves-2.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="highlights-item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://palloi.github.io/responsive-header-only-css/assets/images/chaves-3.jpg">
        </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="highlights-item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://palloi.github.io/responsive-header-only-css/assets/images/quico.png">
        </a>
    </figure>

</aside>
```

> A pseudo-classe :first-of-type representa o primeiro elemento de seu tipo entre os filhos de seu elemento pai